# Is there any standard component on the community which can display custom label that supports translation?

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, customlabel, translation

Is there any standard component on the community which can display custom label that supports translation?

If we need to put some text in the community so that this text can be translated, should we develop a custom component or does any standard component which supports that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actaully, many standard components support that. For example, Rich Content Editor supports if multilingual Community feature is used to translate it.

There are steps defined to implement this in this article
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_multilingual_create.htm&type=5

1. Set the default language for your community. It’s important to set
   the default language before you add translated content to your
   community.
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_multilingual_default.htm&type=5
2. Add languages to the community.
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_multilingual_add.htm&type=5
3. Set options for each language, such as the display label and
   fallback language.
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_multilingual_settings.htm&type=5
4. Either translate content directly on the page in Experience Builder
   or export and prepare the content, and send it for translation and
   then import the translated content.

   a.  Edit language content on the page
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_multilingual_editing_about.htm&type=5

   b.      Export content
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_multilingual_export.htm&type=5#community_builder_multilingual_export

   c.  Import content
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_multilingual_import.htm&type=5#community_builder_multilingual_import
5. Add a Language Selector component to your community pages, so
   unauthenticated community users can choose their preferred language.
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_language_picker.htm&type=5#rss_language_picker